# AngularJS best practice using ng-hide / ng-show, page looking ugly until library is loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having a huge html page with some divs with background colors, etc, using ng-hide, ng-show is looking .. "ugly" until the angularjs library is loaded, as only then they are hidden.  How should I approach this ? Should I use predefined css such as display:hidden ?

Comment: This is way too broad to be addressed as asked.  There are many different ways to handle this, depending on your HTML structure, your javascript structure, your routing options, and a whole host of other factors.  Without code showing the way your application is structured, this is just simply not answerable.

Comment: i agree it's broad, but you may want to look at ng-if

Comment: @ergonaut - It won't make any difference, the point is that angular is not instantiated at the beginning and cannot handle any directive for a initial couple of mili-seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably `ng-cloak`:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Exactly my friend, this is what I was looking for, nevertheless is not so "broad" after all :) Thank you

Comment: This is THE answer. I'm surprised at those people who are closing questions they can't answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I found to tackle this issue is to have absolutely no angular-related logic in your index except for ng-app and `<ui-view></ui-view>` (or ngView, however ui-router is strongly recommended). Then set your routes to display given template with all your ng-goodies. At the point template is displayed, angular is already working and will precompile all the templates before they are displayed.

If your app is extremely simple and using a router seems like an overkill, you can always use ngInclude directive.

The only remaining issue is a completely blank page before angular gets to do stuff. You can use require.js to handle that and to display nice `page loading` widget before angular jumps in.